# Select ReSharper recommendation without using arrow keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

Assume I have the following..

```
public void DoSomething()
{
   var foo = 1 + bar;
}
```

If I type `var b` ReSharper will recommend bar for the variable name.  The problem then is that I need to press the down key and enter to select the recommendation.  Is there a quicker way to select the top option?

I'd rather avoid having to create an AutoHotKey shortcut...

** UPDATE **

My primary concern is not having my hands leave the home row as I'm a heavy Viemu user.

Comment: Oh and I rarely ever use my mouse..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press `Ctrl+Space`, and the only option on the list (that is, "bar") will be automatically committed.

The other answer is perfectly valid as well

Actually as soon as you're in this caret position:

```
var foo = 1 + bar|
```

you can Alt+Enter to see ReSharper suggest different declaration option where "Create local variable 'bar'" will be the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Place you cursor on `bar`, press ALT+Enter and select "create local variable 'bar'" by pressing 'Enter', fill out the type and you're done. So in effect it's: mouse click, ALT+Enter, Enter, v, a, r, TAB

No Arrow key involved unless you don't have a mouse.

Comment: Between ReSharper & Viemu I don't use my mouse very much.. sorry should have been more explicit as to why I didn't want to use the arrow key.  Don't want to leave home row